# pandas Datafram: Add every month of a whole year starting from Dec to Dec for every new Person

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe like this.

```
M_Yr       Type    ID      Name   Sum  
12/31/22   CASH    3512           23
12/31/22   CASH    3513    Mike   3
12/31/22   CASH    3514    Mo     4
12/31/22   CASH    3515    Mary   5
12/31/22   CASH    3516    Mel    10
12/31/22   CASH    3517    Mop    2
12/31/22   CASH    3518    Me     7
1/31/23    CASH    3512           0
1/31/23    CASH    3514    Mo     0
1/31/23    CASH    3515    Mary   -2
1/31/23    CASH    3516    Mel    0
1/31/23    CASH    3517    Mop    2
3/30/23    CASH    3512           6
3/30/23    CASH    3518    Me     0
3/30/23    CASH    3514    Mo     3
3/30/23    CASH    3515    Mary   0
3/30/23    CASH    3516    Mel    0
3/30/23    CASH    3517    Mop    2 
5/31/23    CASH    3512           -2
5/31/23    CASH    3518    Me     3
5/31/23    CASH    3514    Mo     0
5/31/23    CASH    3515    Mary   0
5/31/23    CASH    3516    Mel    1
5/31/23    CASH    3517    Mop    0 
7/31/23    CASH    3512           0
7/31/23    CASH    3518    Me     3
7/31/23    CASH    3514    Mo     0
7/31/23    CASH    3515    Mary   1
7/31/23    CASH    3516    Mel    0
7/31/23    CASH    3517    Mop    0 
8/31/23    CASH    3512           2
8/31/23    CASH    3518    Me     -3
8/31/23    CASH    3514    Mo     0
11/30/23   CASH    3512           0
12/31/23   CASH    3518    Me     3
```

I want to get the Dataframe to print every M_Yr for an entire year for every Name and find the new sum of the sum col for every month using the first numbers given as a starting point and the previous months don't get altered once you get a new sum for the month, so the resulting Dataframe should look like:

```
M_Yr       Type    ID      Name   Sum  
12/31/22   CASH    3512           23
12/31/22   CASH    3513    Mike   3
12/31/22   CASH    3514    Mo     4
12/31/22   CASH    3515    Mary   5
12/31/22   CASH    3516    Mel    10
12/31/22   CASH    3517    Mop    2
12/31/22   CASH    3518    Me     7
1/31/23    CASH    3512           23
1/31/23    CASH    3513    Mike   3
1/31/23    CASH    3514    Mo     4
1/31/23    CASH    3515    Mary   3
1/31/23    CASH    3516    Mel    10
1/31/23    CASH    3517    Mop    4
1/31/23    CASH    3518    Me     7
2/30/23    CASH    3512           23
2/30/23    CASH    3513    Mike   3
2/30/23    CASH    3514    Mo     4
2/30/23    CASH    3515    Mary   3
2/30/23    CASH    3516    Mel    10
2/30/23    CASH    3517    Mop    4
2/30/23    CASH    3518    Me     7
3/31/23    CASH    3512           29
3/31/23    CASH    3513    Mike   3
3/31/23    CASH    3514    Mo     7
3/31/23    CASH    3515    Mary   3
3/31/23    CASH    3516    Mel    10
3/31/23    CASH    3517    Mop    6
3/31/23    CASH    3518    Me     7
4/30/23    CASH    3512           23
4/30/23    CASH    3513    Mike   3
4/30/23    CASH    3514    Mo     7
4/30/23    CASH    3515    Mary   3
4/30/23    CASH    3516    Mel    10
4/30/23    CASH    3517    Mop    6
4/30/23    CASH    3518    Me     7
5/31/23    CASH    3512           27
5/31/23    CASH    3513    Mike   3
5/31/23    CASH    3514    Mo     7
5/31/23    CASH    3515    Mary   3
5/31/23    CASH    3516    Mel    11
5/31/23    CASH    3517    Mop    6
5/31/23    CASH    3518    Me     10
6/30/23    CASH    3512           23
6/30/23    CASH    3513    Mike   3
6/30/23    CASH    3514    Mo     7
6/30/23    CASH    3515    Mary   3
6/30/23    CASH    3516    Mel    11
6/30/23    CASH    3517    Mop    6
6/30/23    CASH    3518    Me     10
7/31/23    CASH    3512           23
7/31/23    CASH    3513    Mike   3
7/31/23    CASH    3514    Mo     7
7/31/23    CASH    3515    Mary   4
7/31/23    CASH    3516    Mel    11
7/31/23    CASH    3517    Mop    6
7/31/23    CASH    3518    Me     13
8/30/23    CASH    3512           29
8/30/23    CASH    3513    Mike   3
8/30/23    CASH    3514    Mo     7
8/30/23    CASH    3515    Mary   4
8/30/23    CASH    3516    Mel    11
8/30/23    CASH    3517    Mop    6
8/30/23    CASH    3518    Me     10
9/31/23    CASH    3512           29
9/31/23    CASH    3513    Mike   3
9/31/23    CASH    3514    Mo     7
9/31/23    CASH    3515    Mary   4
9/31/23    CASH    3516    Mel    11
9/31/23    CASH    3517    Mop    6
9/31/23    CASH    3518    Me     10
10/31/23   CASH    3512           29
10/31/23   CASH    3513    Mike   3
10/31/23   CASH    3514    Mo     7
10/31/23   CASH    3515    Mary   4
10/31/23   CASH    3516    Mel    11
10/31/23   CASH    3517    Mop    6
10/31/23   CASH    3518    Me     10
11/30/23   CASH    3512           29
11/30/23   CASH    3513    Mike   3
11/30/23   CASH    3514    Mo     7
11/30/23   CASH    3515    Mary   4
11/30/23   CASH    3516    Mel    11
11/30/23   CASH    3517    Mop    6
11/30/23   CASH    3518    Me     10
12/31/23   CASH    3512           29
12/31/23   CASH    3513    Mike   3
12/31/23   CASH    3514    Mo     7
12/31/23   CASH    3515    Mary   4
12/31/23   CASH    3516    Mel    11
12/31/23   CASH    3517    Mop    6
12/31/23   CASH    3518    Me     13
```

not sure how to approach

Comment: What have you tried?  This is not a code-writing service.  Note that this kind of thing is probably easier done with your data before it goes into pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with all combinations of columns with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) first and then use cumulative sum per groups by [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
df = (df.set_index(["M_Yr","Type","ID", "Name"])
        .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df["M_Yr"].unique(),
                                             df["Type"].unique(),
                                             df["ID"].unique(),
                                             df["Name"].unique()], 
                                             names=["M_Yr","Type","ID", "Name"]), 
                  fill_value=0)
        .reset_index())

df['Sum'] = df.groupby(['Type','ID','Name'], dropna=False)['Sum'].cumsum()
print (df.tail(10))
        M_Yr  Type    ID  Name  Sum
46  11/30/23  CASH  3512   Mel   11
47  11/30/23  CASH  3512   Mop    6
48  11/30/23  CASH  3512    Me   10
49  12/31/23  CASH  3512   NaN   29
50  12/31/23  CASH  3512  Mike    3
51  12/31/23  CASH  3512    Mo    7
52  12/31/23  CASH  3512  Mary    4
53  12/31/23  CASH  3512   Mel   11
54  12/31/23  CASH  3512   Mop    6
55  12/31/23  CASH  3512    Me   13
```

EDIT: Answer was edited wth mapping by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by original names by `id`s:

```
d = df.set_index('ID')['Name'].to_dict()    

df = (df.set_index(["M_Yr","Type","ID"])
        .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df["M_Yr"].unique(),
                                             df["Type"].unique(),
                                             df["ID"].unique()], 
                                             names=["M_Yr","Type", "ID"]), 
                  fill_value=0)
        .reset_index())

df['Sum'] = df.groupby(['Type','ID'], dropna=False)['Sum'].cumsum()

df['Name'] = df['ID'].map(d)
print (df.tail(10))
        M_Yr  Type    ID  Name  Sum
46  11/30/23  CASH  3516   Mel   11
47  11/30/23  CASH  3517   Mop    6
48  11/30/23  CASH  3518    Me   10
49  12/31/23  CASH  3512   NaN   29
50  12/31/23  CASH  3513  Mike    3
51  12/31/23  CASH  3514    Mo    7
52  12/31/23  CASH  3515  Mary    4
```

EDIT1: First for avoid duplicates is aggregate `sum` per all 4 columns:

```
df = df.groupby(["M_Yr","Type","ID", "Name"], as_index=False, dropna=False)['Sum'].sum()

d = df.set_index('ID')['Name'].to_dict()
```

then for add missing months are used month periods:

```
df["M_Yr"] = pd.to_datetime(df["M_Yr"]).dt.to_period('m')

dates = pd.period_range(df["M_Yr"].min(), df['M_Yr'].max(), freq='m')
```

So `reindex` add all missing combinations:

```
df = (df.set_index(["M_Yr","Type","ID"])
        .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates,
                                             df["Type"].unique(),
                                             df["ID"].unique()], 
                                             names=["M_Yr","Type", "ID"]), 
                  fill_value=0)
        .reset_index())
```

Then cumulative sum per groups, mapping `Name` and convert month periods to dates in format `MM/DD/YYYY`:

```
df['Sum'] = df.groupby(['Type','ID'], dropna=False)['Sum'].cumsum()

df['Name'] = df['ID'].map(d)

df['M_Yr'] = df['M_Yr'].dt.to_timestamp(how='e').dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
print (df)
          M_Yr  Type    ID  Name   Sum
0   12/31/2022  CASH  3512     2   0.0
1   12/31/2022  CASH  3514    Mo   4.0
2   12/31/2022  CASH  3515  Mary   5.0
3   12/31/2022  CASH  3516   Mel  10.0
4   12/31/2022  CASH  3517   Mop   2.0
..         ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
86  12/31/2023  CASH  3515  Mary   4.0
87  12/31/2023  CASH  3516   Mel  11.0
88  12/31/2023  CASH  3517   Mop   6.0
89  12/31/2023  CASH  3513  Mike   3.0
90  12/31/2023  CASH  3518    Me  13.0

[91 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: I forgot to add that every Name has a unique ID and not all of them are 3512 which makes the code not work

Comment: @DumbCoder - Can you change data by this? Because hard to know how change my solution.

Comment: I made the change hopefully it makes more sense now

Comment: I am getting a ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi index!

Comment: @DumbCoder - before solution aggreagte `sum` like `df = df.groupby(["M_Yr","Type","ID", "Name"], as_index=False, dropna=False)['Sum'].sum()`

Comment: not sure what you mean I tried this and I still get the same error, should I try something else?

Comment: @DumbCoder - Do you run before my solution `df = df.groupby(["M_Yr","Type","ID", "Name"], as_index=False, dropna=False)['Sum'].sum()` and still error?

Comment: yes I run it before the solution and I get an error. It says object has not attribute

Comment: @DumbCoder no idea what is problém, for me working Nice.

Comment: I got it to work a different way, but it is missing all the other months in between